# JSON.registerObjectMarshaller doesn't work in bootstrap

Tags: json, grails, groovy, bootstrapping

When I want to test a customized "render as JSON " method, I used the following code

```
class BootStrap{
def init = { servletContext ->
 ....
 println "change the json before format"
 JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {
     println "JSON DATE MARSHAL"
     return it.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
     }
 println "change the json after format"
 }
}
```

but what printed in the console is like this:

> | Compiling 1 source files
>
> | Running Grails application
>
> Active MQ start. ConsumerURL is failover:ssl://xxx.
>
> **change the json before format**
>
> **change the json after format**
>
> |Server running. Browse to http://xxx

the strange thing is that the "JSON DATE MARSHAL"didn't be printed.
But it worked when I put the code in a controller.

I don't know what happened.

Any suggestion will be appretiated.

---

Update:
Like railsdog said, it seems the closure in the init didn't work.

What I supposed the date format in JSON is like this:2016-12-15 16:44:21

But what I get is 2016-12-15T08:44:21Z.

When I put the marshaller in controller, it worked, and the date format in JSON is as expected:

2016-12-15 16:44:21.

I also get the console output:"JSON DATE MARSHAL".

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that registering the object marshaller doesn't actually execute/invoke the closure, hence no debug is emitted.

Comment: Thank for reply. I try to put marshaller in controller and it worked.　I get the debug printout and date format as expected.

Comment: When I test it in a demo project ,it works.Seems like my project or IDE(idea) problem.

Comment: But the println in marshaller will not be excuted until the   render xx as JSON was called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering marshaller check out property `grails.databinding.dateformats` in your grails application config. You can add there more different date formats which should be handled by your app.

Comment: Michal_Szulc, thank you for advice. Still don't know why the closure dosen't work.